# is it possible to have something like "foreach n" rather than "foreach" in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

i have a hbase table where i am storing depth values as one of the column along with few other values in different columns.i have fetched the required data using HbaseStorage().now i have to take these depth values "5 at a time" and perform some analytics on rest the fields corresponding to these 5 depth values and emit the final result for all the 5 rows as one set. i am not getting how can i take 5 depth values at a time and do the operation.it is somewhat like doing "foreach n" instead of "foreach"..need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something with 5 subsequent rows, here is a possibility:

1. Rank all rows
2. Use four joins (rank==rank+1) to combine everything into one block of data

One should of course also consider the possibility of storing in 5 columns rather than 5 rows, but this may not be practical.